# Having an error missing keyword in my query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT TXCM_CATEGORY_ID,
       TXCM_CATEGORY_NAME,
       TXCM_MAIN_CATEGORY_ID,
       TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID,
       CASE
          WHEN TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID = 3097 THEN TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID = 0
          ELSE TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID = 6
       END
  FROM TXODOC_CATEGORY_MASTER;
```

please help me... thanks

Comment: I don't see how this is related to java or jsp.

Comment: Yes retagged it to sql . unsure of the database still

Comment: Whats the assignment in CASE for? To return 0/6: `CASE WHEN TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID = 3097 THEN 0 ELSE 6 END AS TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID `

Comment: Are you sure it is the error you are getting.

Comment: yes.... its an error

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT TXCM_CATEGORY_ID,
       TXCM_CATEGORY_NAME,
       TXCM_MAIN_CATEGORY_ID,
       TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID,
       CASE
          WHEN TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID = 3097 THEN  0
          ELSE 6
       END AS TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID
  FROM TXODOC_CATEGORY_MASTER;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you've got your CASE statement a little messed up.

The [correct syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is like this.

Simple CASE expression:

```
CASE input_expression 
    WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
    [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Searched CASE expression:

```
CASE
    WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
    [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

If I've not mistaken what your after then you can use a searched CASE expression, like this.

```
SELECT
    TXCM_CATEGORY_ID,
    TXCM_CATEGORY_NAME,
    TXCM_MAIN_CATEGORY_ID,
    TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID,
    CASE TXCM_PRT_CATEGORY_ID
        WHEN 3097 THEN 0
        ELSE 6
    END
FROM TXODOC_CATEGORY_MASTER
```